# I wants to get coordinate from matplotlib Rectangle Selector

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use Rectangle Selector from matplotlib to crop some image
It can print the position that I click and release, but I can't save the coordinate data of them.
What should I do to save those coordinate data where I click and release as variables?
For example, after I run the code, it will only print something like(2.14, -0.62) --> (5.86, 0.74). (2.14, -0.62) is the coordinate data of the point I click and (5.86, 0.74) is the point I release. But I hope I can have some variable to save this two coordinate date like: xclick = 2.14, yclick = -0.62, xrelease = 5.86, yrelease = 0.74, but I could not find a way to do it.
I know the x,y coordinate might save in x1,y1,x2,y2, but when I want to call four of them, it return "name 'x1' is not defined" and they are also not in my variables explorer.

Below is my code from matplotlib example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def line_select_callback(eclick, erelease):
    print(eclick.xdata)
    'eclick and erelease are the press and release events'
    x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
    x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
    print("(%3.2f, %3.2f) --> (%3.2f, %3.2f)" % (x1, y1, x2, y2))
    print(" The button you used were: %s %s" % (eclick.button, 
erelease.button))


def toggle_selector(event):
    print(' Key pressed.')
    if event.key in ['Q', 'q'] and toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print(' RectangleSelector deactivated.')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(False)
    if event.key in ['A', 'a'] and not toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print(' RectangleSelector activated.')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(True)


fig, current_ax = plt.subplots()                 # make a new plotting range
N = 100000                                       # If N is large one can see
x = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, N)                    # improvement by use     blitting!

plt.plot(x, +np.sin(.2*np.pi*x), lw=3.5, c='b', alpha=.7)  # plot something
plt.plot(x, +np.cos(.2*np.pi*x), lw=3.5, c='r', alpha=.5)
plt.plot(x, -np.sin(.2*np.pi*x), lw=3.5, c='g', alpha=.3)

print("\n      click  -->  release")

# drawtype is 'box' or 'line' or 'none'
toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(current_ax, line_select_callback,
                                   drawtype='box', useblit=True,
                                   button=[1, 3],  # don't use middle button
                                   minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                                   spancoords='pixels',
                                   interactive=True,state_modifier_keys =     'extents')
plt.connect('key_press_event', toggle_selector)
plt.show()
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: The [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.RectangleSelector) tell us about the `modifier_keys`: *"state_modifier_keys are keyboard modifiers that affect the behavior of the widget.
The defaults are: `dict(move=’ ‘, clear=’escape’, square=’shift’, center=’ctrl’)`"* So you need to provide a dictionary like this to prevent the error. However, It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here and even less how `modifier_keys` are related to that. Please update the question to explain exactly what problem you have.

Comment: after I run this code, it will print the x, y data of the points I click and release, I want to save the x, y data as variable.

Comment: The coordinates *are* saved in the variables `x1`, `y1`, `x2` and `y2`. So it's not clear what you want. Maybe also read [ask] and then explain clearly what you are trying to achieve *in the question*, not in the comments.

Comment: Sorry, I already update my question, I just find out how to edit my question after I reply your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables `x1`, `y1`, `x2` and `y2` are in the local scope of the `line_select_callback` function. You may turn them globally accessible using the `global` statement.

```
def line_select_callback(eclick, erelease):
    global x1, y1, x2, y2
    x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
    x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
```

Or you can assign them to a globally defined list,

```
click = [None,None]
release = [None,None]

def line_select_callback(eclick, erelease):
    click[:] = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
    release[:] = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
```